# dojo amd init method autorun

Tags: javascript, dojo, initialization

I have a js looks like:

```
    abinit();
    function abinit(){}
    function hello{var a=12; return a;}

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
        function(/* function FrameRequestCallback // callback,// DOMElement Element  element){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
     })();
```

AMD converted code looks like below

```
 define(["dojo/ready","dojo/dom","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base /fx","dojo/fx","dojo/dom-style","dojo/parser","dojo/window", "dojo/dom-attr","dojo/domReady!"],  
     function(ready,dom,domConstruct,baseFx,coreFx,domStyle,parser,win,domAttr,) {
       var abGlobal = this;
       abGlobal.abStatus = false;
       return{
            abInit:function() { ...... },
            hellow:function(){var a=12; return a;}
      }
});
```

Got few questions

1. how to call init method when i convert it into dojo amd?
2. how to convert requestAnimFrame according to dojo?
3. what is the correct approach as per AMD (methods inside return or var ={function abInit()} way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to return a "Class" using `declare` and call your method in the `constructor`.

Example here:

```
define([
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/_base /fx",
        "dojo/fx",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/window",
        "dojo/dom-attr",
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
      function(ready, dom, domConstruct, baseFx, coreFx, domStyle, parser, win, domAttr, ) {
        var abGlobal = this;
        abGlobal.abStatus = false;
        return declare(null,{
          constructor:function(){
            this.abInit(); // call your init here
          },
          abInit: function() {
          },
          hellow: function() {
            var a = 12;
            return a;
          }
        });
      });
```

Or return and object after, call your method after requiring your module, example:

```
define([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/_base /fx",
    "dojo/fx",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/window",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(ready, dom, domConstruct, baseFx, coreFx, domStyle, parser, win, domAttr, ) {
    var abGlobal = this;
    abGlobal.abStatus = false;
    // return an object here
    return { 
      abInit: function() {
      },
      hellow: function() {
        var a = 12;
        return a;
      }
    };
  });

  require(['yourModule'],function(yourModule){
    yourModule.abInit(); // call your method here

  });
```

Comment: Thanks.used 2nd solution,its working. how to convert requestAnimFrame according to dojo

Comment: @angel I think there is no similar feature in dojo for requestAnimFrame, so you can simply implement it as vanilla js in your app.

Comment: if you found out my answer useful, please do not forget to accept the answer :) clicking the green mark on the left side. thanks

Comment: init is working fine now but when am making an xhr call, then widget registry values are undefined.do i need to make an init call again after xhr response?

Comment: @angel please consider creating a jsfiddle with the minim viable code in order to reproduce your error. Please post it as a new question and we will more than glad to help you out :)